# plotly_click does not trigger

Tags: onclick, plotly, plotly.js, plotly-python

Following this example https://community.plot.ly/t/hyperlink-to-markers-on-map/17858/6, I am trying to make points my scatter plot clickable (specifically, open a webpage when clicked). How do I get the click event to trigger when a data point is clicked?

This is a python turbogears app, with the `plotly_click` event happening in `js`. I'm using `plotly.js v1.44.1.`. Like in the example, I first create the `fig`:

```
plotlyHtml = webhelpers2.html.literal(plotly.offline.plot(fig, include_plotlyjs=True, output_type='div'))
```

Then I find a `div` in the figure:

```
res = re.search('<div id="([^"]*)"', plotlyHtml)
div_id = res.groups()[0]
```

Then I build a `js callback` to be inserted into a `script` tag in the template, as in the example. Here's the script tag injected into the html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


        var plot_element = document.getElementById('3f56277f-e84b-4b68-ae85-91d3cd62d01c');
        console.log('callback js has been added to page. did we get plot_element?');
        console.log(plot_element);

        plot_element.on('plotly_click', function(data){
            console.log('Im inside the plotly_click!!');
            console.log(data);
            var point = data.points[0];
            if (point) {
                console.log(point.customdata);
                window.open(point.customdata);
            }
        })


</script>
```

The first two `console.log` statements before the event listener print when the page is rendered, meaning the `js` is successfully injected into the `html`. Particularly, `plot_element` is a div with `class="plotly-graph-div js-plotly-plot"`. However clicking points on my scatterplot never results in anything, no errors, events, or console log statements. I at least expect the console log statements in the `if` to occur. Am I selecting the wrong div id?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in my `layout`. I had `'clickmode': 'select'`, which screwed things up. Removing that enabled events to fire as expected.